# Access to function declaration in matlab

Tags: matlab, convolution

function for convolution in matlab is `conv()`. My question is how can I get the actual implementation of the function itself?

Comment: What is your question, exactly?

Comment: Implement inside the function == >  CONV() .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two ways :

1. Approach 1

   When you implement `conv()` or any function (either user defined or in-buit) just right click on the function and click **open** to see function script.
2. Approach 2

   write `open conv()` in the command window. `conv()` can be any function

---

convolution function :

```
function c = conv(a, b, shape)
%CONV Convolution and polynomial multiplication.
%   C = CONV(A, B) convolves vectors A and B.  The resulting vector is
%   length MAX([LENGTH(A)+LENGTH(B)-1,LENGTH(A),LENGTH(B)]). If A and B are
%   vectors of polynomial coefficients, convolving them is equivalent to
%   multiplying the two polynomials.
%
%   C = CONV(A, B, SHAPE) returns a subsection of the convolution with size
%   specified by SHAPE:
%     'full'  - (default) returns the full convolution,
%     'same'  - returns the central part of the convolution
%               that is the same size as A.
%     'valid' - returns only those parts of the convolution 
%               that are computed without the zero-padded edges. 
%               LENGTH(C)is MAX(LENGTH(A)-MAX(0,LENGTH(B)-1),0).
%
%   Class support for inputs A,B: 
%      float: double, single
%
%   See also DECONV, CONV2, CONVN, FILTER, XCORR, CONVMTX.
%
%   Note: XCORR and CONVMTX are in the Signal Processing Toolbox.


%   Copyright 1984-2013 The MathWorks, Inc.

if ~isvector(a) || ~isvector(b)
  error(message('MATLAB:conv:AorBNotVector'));
end

if nargin < 3
    shape = 'full';
end

if ~ischar(shape) && ~(isstring(shape) && isscalar(shape))
  error(message('MATLAB:conv:unknownShapeParameter'));
    end
    if isstring(shape)
        shape = char(shape);
    end
    
    % compute as if both inputs are column vectors
    c = conv2(a(:),b(:),shape);
    
    % restore orientation
    if shape(1) == 'f' || shape(1) == 'F'  %  shape 'full'
        if length(a) > length(b)
            if size(a,1) == 1 %row vector
                c = c.';
            end
        else
            if size(b,1) == 1 %row vector
                c = c.';
            end
        end
    else
        if size(a,1) == 1 %row vector
            c = c.';
        end
    end
end
if isstring(shape)
    shape = char(shape);
end

% compute as if both inputs are column vectors
c = conv2(a(:),b(:),shape);

% restore orientation
if shape(1) == 'f' || shape(1) == 'F'  %  shape 'full'
    if length(a) > length(b)
        if size(a,1) == 1 %row vector
            c = c.';
        end
    else
        if size(b,1) == 1 %row vector
            c = c.';
        end
    end
else
    if size(a,1) == 1 %row vector
        c = c.';
    end
end
```

**Update :**

This is not related to the question. Anyway, you want to calculate convolution integral but the `conv()` function definition in matlab   is :

`w = conv(u,v)` returns the convolution of *vectors* u and v. If u and v are vectors of polynomial coefficients, convolving them is equivalent to multiplying the two polynomials.

Consider that this is **discrete** convolution and does not give you a formula for the result. If you need formulas for the result, then use the symbolic toolbox to calculate the [Convolution Integral](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Convolution).

---

see this [convolution](http://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/fileexchange/28157-convolution)

Comment: enter image description here

but Convolution is sigma

for i = -n:n

end for

correct?

I do not see Something like for in code

Answer (score 5):

If you want to understand how conv() works or make your own version of the conv-function you can always type

```
open conv
```

in the command window. Then you could take a look at the original function and (if necessary) save it under a new name and use your edited version.